# MySQL Insert into multiple databases - issue

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-databases

I have two DB real and backDB. I would like to copy everything from one to a other with SQL... it seems not that easy. If anyone could help me out. Here is my code:

```
$newdbsql="CREATE TABLE $newdb LIKE $actdbname.`$acttable`";
$newresult = mysql_query($newdbsql, $bckconn) or die(mysql_error());

// copy all the data
$query = "INSERT INTO $newdb SELECT * FROM $actdbname.$acttable WHERE $acttable.azon < $upto";
$result = mysql_query($query, $bckconn) or die(mysql_error());
```

I've been fighting with it but I can't get it right... thanks

Update:
I can connect both DB and I can do simple selects as well. But where I want to read from A and copy to BackupDb it always connect just to one DB.

Error message:
SELECT command denied to "backup"user on the real DB...

Important info: I am on shared host so it is not that easy:)

Comment: What isn't working corerctly? What is the error you recieve?

Comment: thanks I have updated it says that the backup user can't have access to the real servers DB.

Comment: Are you aware of [MySQL replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html)? This is not a problem you should try to solve in code.

Comment: What you search for is called _database replication_. Possible related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278163/how-to-code-php-mysql-class-for-master-and-slave-setup

Comment: @Asaph Both have their place though. Replication is usually live and on all the time. It does _not_ protect you from messing up one database with an errant statement, since the same error gets replicated to the other as well (unless you switch replication on and off as a backup system).This is more like a live SQL dump that only happens intermittently.

Comment: @Asaph I am on shared host. So I can mysqldump from phpmyadmin but not from commands. But any code or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to grant `SELECT` permissions to the backup database user to the regular database:

```
GRANT SELECT ON `$actdbname`.* TO `backup`@`localhost`;
```

For best security, it isn't recommended to grant anything other than `SELECT`, since no other permissions should be needed.

Comment: I think this is would be the solution but I am not sure if I can do on a share host so I can't give access... I think but I will double check that. Thanks

Comment: GRANT SELECT ON `realuser`.* TO 'bckuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;  this is how it worked can you tell me what is the different between yours and my (came from my host provider) thx

Comment: @AndrasSebestyen `WITH GRANT OPTION` would permit the `bckuser` user account to use  `GRANT` statements and grant privs to other users. That may not be needed in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

> **Warning:**
>
> Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)?
>
> Instead, you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) should give some details about deciding which API to use. For PDO, here is a [good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

To replicate the database without using MySQL's internal replication feature, you can use the `CREATE TABLE foo LIKE bar;` and `INSERT INTO foo SELECT * FROM bar;` statements.

The first line will create a new table named `foo` using the exact same **structure** what `bar` had originally, and the second line will help you copy the whole **contents** of `bar` into `foo`.

#### Edit:

The table names can be said as `foo`, it will mean the `foo` table in your current database. But you can say `baz.foo`, which will mean the `foo` table in your `baz` database. Of course, your users needs the required privileges to have on both databases. The following code works:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("original");

mysql_query("CREATE TABLE backup.foo LIKE original.bar");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO backup.foo SELECT * FROM original.bar");

mysql_close();
```

Comment: thanks the problem is I am using two Database so access is an issue $result = mysql_query($query, $bckconn) as the Insert run on the bckserver I cant access to the real access???

Comment: thanks I am struggling with the permission the rest of it worked when I used only one DB-t

Comment: @AndrasSebestyen You will need `SELECT`, `INSERT` and `CREATE` privileges on both databases. The two databases needs to be on the same host.