# how i would achieve Master slave connection in Zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Actually, I was Implements  master slave connection in my project on Zend framework 2 using this link [configure multiple databases in zf2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003187/configure-multiple-databases-in-zf2). But that solution mades too many changes in my existing project. So, I want to avoid that changes and implements master slave connection in minimum changes.
so, how can achieve ?

Comment: Possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278163/how-to-code-php-mysql-class-for-master-and-slave-setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of You are Using tablegateway in zf2 You can use the MasterSlave Feature.

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html#tablegateway-features